# How do set I the first three tabs in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs

I would like first three tabs to always be: Gmail, Contacts, & Calendar. This seems to be default on my wife's Chrome.  How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Open Gmail, Contacts, & Calendar in three separate tabs in Chrome, right click on header of each tab, and click on "Pin Tab". The pinned tab will always be first tabs when you open the browser.

Comment: Yeah, and another option through the settings - startup pages

Answer (score 0):

Question title seems to be different that the description. If you want to open this three pages automatically after each start of Chrome, you should add them in **Settings --> On startup --> Open a specific page or set of pages**

Comment: You're right, I did a mistake while editing. The other answer is correct and this question is not a duplicate. I clarified the title.